# Slow performance in populating DataGridView with large data

Tags: c#, performance, datagridview

I am using a `BindingSource` control ([reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.8)) to populate my `DataGridView` control. There are around 1000+ records populating on it. I am using threading to do so. The `DataGridView` performs very slow in this case.

I tried to set `DoubleBuffered` property to true, `RowHeadersWidthSizeMode` to disabled, `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to none. But still the same behavior.

How can I improve the performance of the Grid?

Comment: think about paging/using filters for data.

Comment: I regularly run into the same problem; I also have several 1000 of records in one list and have to use paging for the records - which solves the problem but raises new problems at the same time!

Comment: one of the most duplicated question on SO

Comment: yes, that's right. Even I feel that what the user will do with thousands of rows. However, it is the current requirement of my client. so I have to do it by any mean :)

Comment: this solved the same problem to me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37735997/2525774

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you have a huge amount of rows, like 10,000 and more,
to avoid performance leaks - do the following before data binding:

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing; 
// or even better, use .DisableResizing. Most time consuming enum is DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders

// set it to false if not needed
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

After the data is bound, you may re-enable it.

Comment: i tried to put your code inside my file.Designer.vb and I tried to run it good properly. As you said, set RowHeadersVisible to False and then... after Binding, make it RowHeadersVisible to True again. That's good solution and it works! But unfortunately, if i made some changes on the GUI (Front), the code that i put inside the file.Designer.vb is changed back to the default rendered by the Visual Studio. How can I handle this? @okarpov ?

Comment: @gumuruh put the disabling code in your from class constructor and put enabling code somewhere after binding

Comment: I've been having ContentSwitchDeadlock issues when loading large amounts (100 000+) rows in a datagridview. Switching from `autoSizeAllHeaders` to `EnableResizing` did the job! Thanks.

Comment: HEY MAN.........A BIG BIG BIG THANKS TO YOU.....LOVE YOU, I tried Improving performance with BackgroundWorker but unable to do that, You saved my lot of time. Thank You so much again

Answer (score 18):

Generally turning auto-sizing off and double buffering help to speed up DataGridView population. Check whether the DGV double buffering is turned on properly:

```
if (!System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
{
  Type dgvType = dataGridView1.GetType();
  PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
  pi.SetValue(dataGridView1, value, null);
}
```

Disabling the redrawing with the WinAPI [WM_SETREDRAW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145219(v=vs.85).aspx) message also helps:

```
// *** API Declarations ***
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);
private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;

// *** DataGridView population ***
SendMessage(dataGridView1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
// Add rows to DGV here
SendMessage(dataGridView1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

If you do not need 2-way data-binding or some features provided by BindingSource (filtering, etc.), you may consider adding rows at one go with the [DataGridView.Rows.AddRange()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The link to the source article with the sample: http://10tec.com/articles/why-datagridview-slow.aspx

Answer (score 17):

Make sure u don't auto-size columns, it improves performance.

i.e. don't do this:

`Datagridview.Columns[I].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.xxxxx;`

Comment: Or what I just did--turn off the auto-sizing while populating the grid, then turn it back on.  I had about 15,000 entries total, I would say the speedup was at least 100x, probably a lot more.

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm late to the party, but I recently got fed up with how slow the auto resizing was for the the DataGridView control, and felt someone somewhere might benefit from my solution.

I created this extension method for manually measuring and resizing columns in a DataGridView.  Set the **AutoSizeColumnsMode** to **DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None** and call this method after setting the DataSource.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides very fast and basic column sizing for large data sets.
/// </summary>
public static void FastAutoSizeColumns(this DataGridView targetGrid)
{
    // Cast out a DataTable from the target grid datasource.
    // We need to iterate through all the data in the grid and a DataTable supports enumeration.
    var gridTable = (DataTable)targetGrid.DataSource;

    // Create a graphics object from the target grid. Used for measuring text size.
    using (var gfx = targetGrid.CreateGraphics())
    {
        // Iterate through the columns.
        for (int i = 0; i < gridTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            // Leverage Linq enumerator to rapidly collect all the rows into a string array, making sure to exclude null values.
            string[] colStringCollection = gridTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<object>(i) != null).Select(r => r.Field<object>(i).ToString()).ToArray();

            // Sort the string array by string lengths.
            colStringCollection = colStringCollection.OrderBy((x) => x.Length).ToArray();

            // Get the last and longest string in the array.
            string longestColString = colStringCollection.Last();

            // Use the graphics object to measure the string size.
            var colWidth = gfx.MeasureString(longestColString, targetGrid.Font);

            // If the calculated width is larger than the column header width, set the new column width.
            if (colWidth.Width > targetGrid.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Size.Width)
            {
                targetGrid.Columns[i].Width = (int)colWidth.Width;
            }
            else // Otherwise, set the column width to the header width.
            {
                targetGrid.Columns[i].Width = targetGrid.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Size.Width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While I certainly would never recommend populating a DGV with 1000+ rows, this method results in a huge performance benefit while producing very similar results to the **AutoResizeColumns** method.

For 10k Rows:  (10K rows * 12 columns.)

**AutoResizeColumns** = ~3000 ms

**FastAutoSizeColumns** = ~140 ms

Comment: I realise I'm commenting nearly two years late but just wanted to say that this really helped me out.

Answer (score 7):

I had to disable auto-sizing in a few places to see the greatest improvement in performance. In my case, I had auto-size modes enabled for `AutoSizeRowsMode`, `AutoSizeColumnsMode`, and `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode`. So I had to disable each of these before binding the data to the `DataGridView`:

```
dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;

// ... Bind the data here ...

// Set the DataGridView auto-size modes back to their original settings.
dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

Comment: In my case it solved the problem as it was a datagridview tooks long to diplay 2000 records after disabling went fast

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, reducing the load time for 10000 rows from ~12 to ~3 seconds. I only needed `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode`, the others were already disabled here. All other solutions provided on this page had no effect or made it worse for the initial loading at startup (which still always completes in only 1 sec).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to override the virtual mode required methods of the DataGridView there is another alternative if you could consider using Listview:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

> - It has a version (FastObjectListView) that can build a list of 100,000
>     objects in less than 0.1 seconds.
> - It has a version (DataListView)
>     that supports data binding, and another (FastDataListView) that
>     supports data binding on large (100,000+) data sets.

Answer (score 3):

Setting
AutoSizeColumnsMode to None and
AutoSizeRowsMode to DisplayedCells
fixed it for me.

Comment: This solved the speed issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had problem with performance when user load 10000 items or sort them.
When I commented line:

```
this.dataEvents.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

Everything became well.

Comment: I also found AutoSizeColumnsMode being set to all can impact performance pretty severely too. Of course the OP mentions they already disabled this but it is helpful to note that it really can help to do so.

Comment: Yes you are right. I did not notice in source topic that it had already been done.

Answer (score 1):

@Bobby L answer is great, but blocks the UI thread. Here's my adaptation which calculates the widths of the column in a BackgroundWorker before applying the calculated values to the UI thread

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker _worker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.DoWork += _worker_DoWork;
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += _worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = GetAutoSizeColumnsWidth(dataGridView1);
    }

    private void _worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetAutoSizeColumnsWidth(dataGridView1, (int[])e.Result);
    }

    private int[] GetAutoSizeColumnsWidth(DataGridView grid)
    {
        var src = ((IEnumerable)grid.DataSource)
            .Cast<object>()
            .Select(x => x.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Select(p => p.GetValue(x, null)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty)
                .ToArray()
            );

        int[] widths = new int[grid.Columns.Count];
        // Iterate through the columns.
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            // Leverage Linq enumerator to rapidly collect all the rows into a string array, making sure to exclude null values.
            string[] colStringCollection = src.Where(r => r[i] != null).Select(r => r[i].ToString()).ToArray();

            // Sort the string array by string lengths.
            colStringCollection = colStringCollection.OrderBy((x) => x.Length).ToArray();

            // Get the last and longest string in the array.
            string longestColString = colStringCollection.Last();

            // Use the graphics object to measure the string size.
            var colWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(longestColString, grid.Font);

            // If the calculated width is larger than the column header width, set the new column width.
            if (colWidth.Width > grid.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Size.Width)
            {
                widths[i] = (int)colWidth.Width;
            }
            else // Otherwise, set the column width to the header width.
            {
                widths[i] = grid.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Size.Width;
            }
        }

        return widths;
    }

    public void SetAutoSizeColumnsWidth(DataGridView grid, int[] widths)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            grid.Columns[i].Width = widths[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

```
for (int z = 0; z < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; z++)
{
   dataGridView1.Columns[z].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
}
... Code where I change the content of dataGridView1 in a loop ...
for (int z = 0; z < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; z++)
{
   dataGridView1.Columns[z].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to consider using your data grid in [virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx).  Basically, you set the extents of the grid up front, then override "OnCellValueNeeded" as required.

You should find (especially for only 1000 or so rows) that your grid population becomes effectively instant.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i resolved it by setting

```
AutoSizeRowsMode to DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
```

And set the same for columns too

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting this a while, I found that the main issue with speed still comes from changing the dataGridView from a non-UI thread.  The code below has completely solved my datagridview populating slowly from a dataTable datasource

```
dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table)
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is simply set visible property of DataGridView to false before loading, after complete set to true.

```vb
    DataGridView1.Visible = False
    
    'fill your data here

    DataGridView1.Visible = True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        Dim asrm = DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode
        Dim ascm = DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode
        Dim chhs = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode

        DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None
        DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing

        DataGridView1.SuspendLayout()
        bs.SuspendBinding()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

        For Each t As obj In lt_list
            bs.Add(t)
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs

        DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
        DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = ascm
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = chhs

        bs.ResumeBinding()
        DataGridView1.ResumeLayout()
```

16000 items,
16 seconds with .DataSource <> Nothing,
300 miliseconds with .DataSource = Nothing

Comment: This is a C# tagged question.