# Fastest way to read 2mb binary file in decimal or hex?

Tags: c#, datagridview, hex, hexdump

im trying to read a binary file into my own hex editor using a datagridview.

this was my initial approach

```
FileStream RawD = new FileStream(ECUFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader RawB = new BinaryReader(RawD);
```

then i've tried just the binary reader as well...

now i'm using

```
MemoryMappedFile RawD = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(ECUFileName);
MemoryMappedViewStream stream = RawD.CreateViewStream();
BinaryReader RawB = new BinaryReader(stream);
```

all i want the code to do is read decimals and put it in a datagridview.
a 2mb file takes forever.

```
while (RawB.BaseStream.Position <= RawB.BaseStream.Length)
{
    if (term == true) break;
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)DataG.Rows[0].Clone();
    DataG.Rows.Add(row);
    for (int P = 0; P < I; P++)
    {
        if (RawB.BaseStream.Position == RawB.BaseStream.Length) break;
        Int16 Byte = RawB.ReadInt16();
        string ByteStr = string.Format("{0}",Byte);
        DataG[P, X].Value = ByteStr;
        DataG[P, X].ReadOnly = true;
        string ADR = string.Format("{0:x6}", X * 10); ;
        DataG.Rows[X].HeaderCell.Value = ADR;
        DataG.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataG.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + 1;
        if (term == true) break;
    }
```

i've just tried this, seems a bit quicker

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ECUFileName);
for (int i=0; i <= bytes.Length; i++)
{
    string result = Convert.ToString(bytes[i]);
    richTextBox1.AppendText(result);
}
```

be hex editor cant be used for what i intend to do, so i have to manually do it.

i have read tons of articles where people say read AllBytes with the file method, to have the file stored in memory,
when i tried the file method, it didn't work fast as well.

Comment: Your slowness is coming from working with the grid, not reading the file.

Comment: You should look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226992/slow-performance-in-populating-datagridview-with-large-data

Comment: And is your MemoryMapped approach any faster? (Seems unlikely).

Comment: Have you tried loading the data into a DataTable and using that as the DataSource for the DataGridView?

Comment: I can't get it faster then ~10 sec for a 2MB file.  You'll have to paginate or use VirtualMode.

Comment: Naming a variable of type `Int16` as "Byte" may not be the best thing to do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed a DataGridView from the toolbox onto a Form and used this code:

```
static void Demo(DataGridView dgv)
{
    string src = @"C:\temp\currentData.txt";
    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(src);
    int nCols = 16; //number of columns to use in the DGV
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < nCols; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int16") });
    }

    var lastIndex = data.Length - nCols - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i += nCols * 2)
    {
        var dr = dt.NewRow();

        for (int j = 0; j <= nCols * 2 - 1; j += 2)
        {
            dr[j / 2] = BitConverter.ToInt16(data, i + j);
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


    dgv.DataSource = dt;

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Demo(dataGridView1);

}
```

Which showed the populated DGV in less than a second. (Using an old i7 920.) Any stupidity in the code (e.g. off-by-one errors) is because I manually translated it from VB.NET. As it is, it does not show the last row of data if it is not a complete row. I'm only demonstrating that it is faster this way. Also, you should make suitable adjustments if the file is not an even number of bytes in length.

**The important part** which makes it faster is that I populate a DataTable to use later as the DataSource for the DGV.

The display of larger files would probably be better done with VirtualMode (as suggested by Hans Passant).