# C# DataGridView CellFormatting

Tags: c#

I've tried turning on double buffering for the DataGridView but the performance is still poor.  Without attaching the CellFormatting event, I use about 5% of my CPU, but with it, my CPU uses 16% - 20%.  With double buffering turned on it is closer to 25%.

Is there an alternative I can use to change the color of the background of the cells?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
        {
            string s = (String)e.Value;
            s = s.Replace(" ",string.Empty);
            if (s != string.Empty && s.Length > 0)
            {
                GUIRow r = gui[e.RowIndex];
                DataGridViewCell cell;

                if(r.imLastBid){//.getSide() == domForm2.BID){

                        cell = dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex];
                        cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Salmon;
                    if(r.count){
                        cell = dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex];
                        cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Salmon;
                    }else{
                        cell = dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex];
                        cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    }

                }else if(r.imLastAsk){
                        cell = dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex];
                        cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkSeaGreen;
                    if(r.count){
                        cell = dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex];
                        cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkSeaGreen;
                    }else{
                        cell = dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex];
                        cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SeaGreen;
                    }



                }
                else{
                    cell = dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex];
                    cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    cell = dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex];
                    cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }

                if(r.imLastPrice){
                    cell = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex];
                    cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

                }else{
                    cell = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex];
                    cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }


            }
            else{
                DataGridViewCell cell;
                cell = dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex];
                cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                cell = dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex];
                cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: My solution was to detach the CellFormattingEvent and manually call the logic above whenever I did a GUI update.  CPU usage went down to about 3 - 4%

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize some of your logic.  Consider this code:

```
string s = (String)e.Value;
s = s.Replace(" ",string.Empty);   // <--- creates a new string, uh oh
if (s != string.Empty && s.Length > 0)
```

You are creating a new string on every paint event.  That's an expensive operation for a GUI event, so avoid the memory allocation if possible.  Instead, use this:

```
string s = (String)e.Value;
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
```

This is how `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is implemented:

```
if (value == null)
{
    return true;
}
for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
{
    if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i]))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

As you can see, it avoids creating a new string.

Try this change by itself and see if your performance improves.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to optimise cell formatting.  I agree there are optimisations to be made there, but I think you'll find that most of the performance issues come from rendering and re-rendering while the grid is populated. For performance I suggest you look at several other common performance problems with DataGridView controls:

1. Hide the DataGridView before binding and/or re-populating and make it visible again after populating.  This often speeds things up immensely.
2. Check (and preferably disable) various autosizing properties either design-time or before data binding, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17785898/2869344):

   ```
   dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing; //or even better .DisableResizing. Default is DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders
   ```
3. Only load the rows that are needed immediately using [Virtual Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-jit-data-loading-in-the-datagrid) and paging.

Comment: I tried hiding, but  my data comes in very quickly, and I update the GUI every 25ms so it ends up just flashing.  
  Here is an example: https://www.screencast.com/t/jYnQR4zf3a.  I will look into implementing the virtual mode