# Fill DataGridView with 25k data slower

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I have a windows form that has a DataGridView (DGVs) that will hold 25,000+ records and 15 columns. Data is filled into the DGVs by bounding through a datatable like the code below

```
grdSearch.AutoGenerateColumns = False
grdSearch.DataSource = dtStock
grdSearch.Columns(colSearchImage.Index).DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = My.Resources.no_image
```

it takes too long (30 secs), and much more.

So my question is, what is the best way to load a DGV with a large amount of data that will take on average <3 - 5 seconds?

**EDIT**

The grid has these two events attached, could it be a contributor to the problem?

```
 Private Sub grdSrch_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdSearch.CellContentClick
        If e.RowIndex = -1 OrElse e.ColumnIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

        Dim PrID As Integer = grdSearch.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colSearchProdID.Index).Value

        If e.ColumnIndex = colSearchDesc.Index Then
            AddProduct(PrID)
        End If
        grdSearch.SendToBack()
        txtSearch.Text = ""
    End Sub



    Private Sub grdSrch_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles grdSearch.CellPainting
        If e.RowIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
        Dim dgr As DataGridViewRow = grdSearch.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        If dgr.Cells(colStockBal.Index).Value - dgr.Cells(colCurrSold.Index).Value <= 0 Then
            grdSearch.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.MistyRose

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226992/slow-performance-in-populating-datagridview-with-large-data Make sure column autoresize property is false and potentially consider [virtual mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-virtual-mode-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) and all else fails paginate.

Comment: You may have code somewhere in an event which is eating up time, but...  When you provide a different image *after* the DGV is filled it will have to go back and redo some stuff.  `AutoColumResizeMode` as AllCells will take a long time, but many of the others like `ColumnHeaders` or `DisplayedCells` only incrementally.  I loaded 125k rows in 7 secs with the special image and ColumnHeaders settings

Comment: @Plutonix do you mean the datagridview events, it has `CellContentClick` and `CellPainting` event which colors the cell based on content, I changed `AutoSIzeColumnMode` and `AutoSIzeRowMode` to Displayed and i also added to two events of the grid in the question

Comment: @JacobH The grid is use as a filter list, the grid appears when a use starts typing in a text box and it displays some data for the use to select, so i guess all data has to be loaded at once

Comment: There is also the possibility that it is taking the DB itself a while to execute the query.  Use a `StopWatch` to  figure out where the time is eaten.  Your should set `Option Strict On` also.  That paint code is going to run multiple times for each row - as many as there are columns to show.  Use the `RowPrePaint` event to run it once per row.  The impact should be minimal since that code will only run for rows that are showing.  My best is some outsized portion in query time.