# Setting DataGridView columns property takes too long

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having a `Form` with only a `DataGridView` inside and I bound `DataSource` to it with 5k rows and after that I change column widths.

Problem here is that when I only set `DataSource` without changing the column's width, The form shows instantly, but when I do column style changing stuff, it takes 3-4 sec to show.

Everything I found on internet was about "datasource binding is slow", but I do not have that problem here.

How can I improve this?

EDIT: Found out that only `AutoSizeColumnMode` takes too long. Why is that?

```
public IzborRobe1(Dokument dokument)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dokument.robaUMagacinuKomercijalno;

    //Without this down code it instantly shows
    dataGridView1.Columns["KATBR"].Width = 100;
    dataGridView1.Columns["KATBRPRO"].Width = 100;
    dataGridView1.Columns["ROBAID"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["NAZIV"].Width = 400;
    dataGridView1.Columns["STANJE"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns["JM"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns["PRODAJNACENA"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    //=======================================================

    numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;
    numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
}
```

Even when I put it inside `Thread()` It takes same time:

```
public IzborRobe1(Dokument dokument)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dokument.robaUMagacinuKomercijalno;

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns["KATBR"].Width = 100;
        dataGridView1.Columns["KATBRPRO"].Width = 100;
        dataGridView1.Columns["ROBAID"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["NAZIV"].Width = 400;
        dataGridView1.Columns["STANJE"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns["JM"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns["PRODAJNACENA"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    });
    t1.Start();

    numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;
    numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
}
```

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447291/43846). Worth looking at the aother answers in that question as well.

Comment: It is working. That answer is underrated.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None` before loading data to Datagridview.