# What are different ways in VB Dot Net to populate DataGridView Grid using SQL Query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I want to populate a DataGridView Grid in my Form with Data from SQL Query or from some Table form Database. I want to know various possible ways to populate the DataGridView Grid.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 3 ways to display data in a DataGridView

1. Create the rows manually in a loop: it's very inefficient if you have a lot of data
2. Use the DataGridView's virtual mode: the DGV only creates as many rows as can be         displayed, and
       dynamically changes their contents when the user scrolls. You need
       to handle the CellValueNeeded event to provide the required data to
       the DGV
3. Use databinding: that's by far the easiest way. You just fill a
       DataTable with the data from the database using a DbDataAdapter, and
       you assign this DataTable to the DGV's DataSource property. The DGV
       can automatically create the columns (AutoGenerateColumns = true),
       or you can create them manually (you must set the DataPropertyName
       of the column to the name of the field you want to display). In
       databound mode, the DGV works like in virtual mode except that it
       takes care of fetching the data from the datasource, so you don't
       have anything to do. It's very efficient even for a large number of
       rows

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580237/best-way-to-fill-datagridview-with-large-amount-of-data).