# What are the options to load huge amount of rows in Winforms DataGrid

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, data-binding, large-data

I need to display data in a C# based Winform DataGridView, the data is almost 1 million rows in total. I want to use BindingSource so that I can do editing operations easily.

Now when I am trying to load the data .NET is throwing OutOfMemory Exception. When I reduced the amount of data to 700000 rows then I am able to load the data but when I tried to edit very first record again .NET throws exception OutOfMemory.

Actually my Winform UI has 1 DataGrid which is on the left side and the Editors are on the right side (List&Detail on the same form)

I am sure what I am not on the right track.

I appreciate if someone kindly guide me best suited strategies to carry on my development in this scenario. I do have option to provide paging but I am confused that how many rows should I page and when should I fetch the next page...in short I am LOST....please guide....

Thanks

Comment: Have a look there [Best way to fill datagridView ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580237/best-way-to-fill-datagridview-with-large-amount-of-data)

Comment: There are numerous questions like this already asked here on SO. Options are setting several properties of the DGV, virtual mode, paging, ...

Comment: @Cupkek05, thanks I have seen this thread already,@Cupkek05, thanks I have seen this thread already, even though I thought I should post my problem. actually I want to provide the normal databinding facilities on the same form like editing, scrolling, filtering etc.. In virtualMode I think there will be limitations in regards to few features and I will need to change my UI like editing on the same form etc..

Comment: That is just a bad idea, period.  Implement something that limits the amount of data you load in one go.  Loading that much data is doomed to fail.  Do matter what you do in testing, there will always be a machine that breaks your assumptions and crashes.

Comment: Also i can't imagine that a single user could ever want to see 1.000.000 rows at once. Even if he had to read each line he could not complete that task in a whole life. You want to be able to filter all rows to just see the specific ones you want. As soon as you filter your rows you will need to display less, which solves the problem.